# #Errors in SSMS built-in reports

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

From my local computer I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio client (SSMS) to connect to a SQL Server installed on a remote computer. I connect using Windows Authentication method.

My SQL Server Management Studio 2016 installed in my local computer shows below versions installed:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.16100.1
Herramientas cliente de Microsoft Analysis Services         13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.17763.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Sistema operativo                                           6.3.17763
```

SQL Server version installed on remote computer is as below:

[image]

When I build reports I get a lot of "#Error" printed on it. As an example, to build a report about all blocked transactions I go to Server node -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Activity – All Blocked Transactions. It shows "#Error", see below screenshot (in this screenshot there are no blocking transactions):

[image]

Comment: Who are you connecting as? I'd suspect either you don't have adequate permissions (though I would also check if the newer version of SSMS 2016, or 17/18, might be better).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am connecting using windows authentication from my SSMS client and pointing to the correct SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It seems it is caused by an out-of-memory exception. Aftern SSMS built-in reports are correctly generated. See my answer.

Comment: It wasn't me who down-voted, but keep in mind people are free to vote however they want, for whatever reasons they have, and are not bound to provide you with an explanation. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/165455), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/61305), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/165455).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it is caused by an out-of-memory exception. Restarting SSMS corrected the problem. After restarting SSMS, built-in reports are correctly generated, no more #Errors are shown.

I found this solution [here](http://sqlpowered.com/en/errors-in-ssms-built-in-reports/).

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this issue now when running the 'Physical Index Usage' report on my acount with sysadmin Server Role.
Restarting SQLSERVER did not fix the issue.

HOWEVER...
Connecting with the 'sa' account the report displays correctly.

I suspect an issue with the user groups as 'SQL Server Agent' also stopped displaying for other users with sysadmin role. Investigations continue...